# Problem reading JSON values from file into array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, associative-array

I am writing a web application showing departures from a preselected station. An id of the selected station is saved as a coockie. A JSON file containing id's and full names is read into an array with the id's as keys and full names as values, like this `Stations[Id] = FullName`. This works just fine when writing to console but not to the html page when it is opened or reloaded, the `checkCoockie()`function. It says `undefined` instead of the station. After a new station has been chosen the stations full name is shown properly, the `setCoockie()`function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>

var Stations = [];

function onLoad() {
    checkCookie();
    return;
}

async function loadStations() {
    fetch("tinystations.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(stations => stations.forEach(item => 
            Stations[item.Id] = item.FullName));
        return;
}

async function checkCookie() {
    await loadStations();
    console.log(Stations);
    var station1 = getCookie("station1");
    document.getElementById("chosen1").innerHTML = station1 + " : " + Stations[station1];
    return;
}

function setCookie() {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 100000000000); // Sufficiant amount of time. 3 years.
    let expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    let station1 = document.getElementById("TIstation1").value;
    document.cookie = "station1=" + station1 + ";" + expires;
    document.getElementById("chosen1").innerHTML = station1 + " : " + Stations[station1];
    return;
}

function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div id="coockie">
        <p>Select new stations</p>
        <input id="TIstation1" type="text" placeholder="Choose station" />
        <button onclick="setCookie()">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div id="chosen">
        Preselected:
        <p id="chosen1"> </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "FullName": "Arlanda C",
        "Id": "Arnc"
    },
    {
        "FullName": "Huddinge",
        "Id": "Hu"
    },
    {
        "FullName": "Jakobsberg",
        "Id": "Jkb"
    },
    {
        "FullName": "Stuvsta",
        "Id": "Stu"
    },
    {
        "FullName": "Rotebro",
        "Id": "R"
    },
    {
        "FullName": "Stockholm City",
        "Id": "Sci"
    }
]
```

When opening or reloading page it look like this:
[image: When opening or reloading page]

And after a new station been chosen and new coockie set:
[image]

I thought the `Stations`array might not be ready when `checkCoockie()` was executed so I made `checkCoockie()` async and made it wait for `loadStations()` to finish. That didn't help. I have tried many async/await solutions the last month but none have helped.
Any suggestions how I can get this to work on page load?

Comment: `loadStations` doesn't need to be `async` since you're not awaiting anything. Technically you just need to `return fetch()` and things should work... I'd suggest though that you remove the global `Stations` variable and instead return a new stations object form your `.then()` and then use `const stations = await loadStations()` when calling `loadStations`.

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks for your comment. Returning `Stations` as a function value has crossed my mind but I rather not go that way. I don't see how I can use `Stations` in the `setCoockie` function. That function is called when I push a button. And I'd prefer not to read the JSON file again. It is not huge but still around 50kb. Another reason is that I set another array in the `loadStations`, not shown in this example because it's working and I wanted to cut out all that's not relevant. I have to give up on this. It's annoying me though, that I can't figure out why it's not working.